# how to get top 5 records in linq with lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I need to get top 5 values of one column "Tempreture" at this time stamp like "select top 5 temperature of the tbl_sensors order by desc "

I tried like this, but I don't know how to get top 5

```
var sensorsVal = DB.tbl_sensors.OrderByDescending(x => x.CurrentTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: how about `.Take(5)`

Comment: i need top 5 tempreture  values, its a column name of tbl_sensors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var sensorsVal = DB.tbl_sensors.OrderByDescending(x => x.CurrentTime)
                   .Select(x => x.temperature)
                   .Take(5);
```

Comment: If needed we can have use with eager loading like var sensorsVal = DB.tbl_sensors.OrderByDescending(x => x.CurrentTime).Select(x => x.temperature).Take(5).ToList();

Comment: can u tell me how to store in json data ?
   return Json(new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { WaterTemperature = parkingSlot.WaterTemperature } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: @rahulkumar - Don't really have much experience with jsons. It'll be best if you ask another question for that.

Comment: im getting blocked.so asking here